# Lemmatization with Microsoft Cognitive Services?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, lemmatization

Microsoft Cognitive Services offers the ability to analyse text using pre-built models. The demo at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/linguistic-analysis-api/ can provide sentence structure and POS tags, but doesn't include lemmatization. Other pages suggest (indirectly) that lemmatization can be achieved using the API and building models from scratch. Can anyone tell me if lemmatization can be performed using the pre-built models? The documentation doesn't seem to reveal anything, but it's functionality that often accompanies what the demo shows.